# Angularjs enabling disabled dropdowns in the ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi in following html code I am using ng-repeat to display all the rows with name and the dropdowns.

```
<div ng-repeat="a in items">
  <div>
    <span>{{a.name}}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select ng-model="a.c_id" ng-options="d.c_id as d.description for d in loclist" ng-disabled="display" ng-change="selected(a.c_id)">
    </select>
  </div>
 <button ng-click="submit(items)">Submit</button>
```

In my controller when value of c_id is 3 it disables the dropdown using following code

```
  $scope.display = false;
    $scope.selected = function (value) {
         this.te = value;
         if (this.te == 3) {
             this.display = true;
         }        
    };
```

Using submit button I want to first enable all the dropdowns that were disabled previously. Using the following code

```
   $scope.submit=function(items)
    {
      for(i=0; i< items.length; i++)
        {
            this.display=false;
        }   
     }
```

It doesnt work. It will not set display=false for the dropdown to be enable. 
Please let me know how to correct this issue so I can reset the display to false.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to bind `ng-disabled` with an item instead of the scope:

```
ng-disabled="a.display"
```

on `ng-change`, pass the item to the function:

```
ng-change="selected(a)"
```

Change your select function to update the display property on an item:

```
$scope.selected = function (item) {
     var value = item.c_id;
     this.te = value;
     if (this.te == 3) {
         item.display = true;
     }        
};
```

In your submit function, just loop through the items and reset the display:

```
$scope.submit=function(items)
    {
      for(i=0; i< items.length; i++)
        {
            items[i].display=false;
        }   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo here

```
ng-click="submit(items)"
```

Correct it as follows `sbumit` to `submit`

```
$scope.submit=function(items)
    {
      for(i=0; i< items.length; i++)
        {
            this.display=false;
        }   
     }
```

Comment: Sorry but that was a typo in writing here, that is not the issue.